# Comment compose-t-on traditionnellement une lettre en français ?

Tags: typographie, correspondance

Quand je rédige mon courrier, j’utilise depuis quelques temps XeTeX, avec l’option `frenchle` du paquet Babel. Cependant, d’autres feuilles styles existent pour rédiger des lettres : notamment `lettre`.

Et les aspects des lettres composées par ces deux outils diffèrent. J’ai donc quelques questions à vous poser sur la structure traditionnelle d’une lettre en français, voire française :

1. Le lieu et la date d’écriture s’indiquent-ils au dessus ou en dessous de l’adresse du destinataire ?
2. Faut-il ou non indenter la première ligne de la lettre ? (Le « Madame Duchmole, » ; « Monsieur Trucmuche, » ou « Madame, Monsieur, ».)

Comment: http://www.modele-lettre-type.com/  ; http://www.la-lettre.com/  ; http://www.bienecrire.org/som-modeles.php  ; etc...

Answer (score 3):

Voici comment j'ai appris à présenter une lettre:

Informations sur l'expéditeur en haut à gauche (nom, adresse, contact, fonction).
Le lieu et la date sont indiqués sur la première ligne (la même que le nom de l'expéditeur donc) mais à droite. (Sous la forme: fait à Ville le Date)
Saut d'une ligne puis à droite les informations sur le destinataire (nom, fonction, entreprise)

Objet: un résumé très bref du contenu de la lettre

La formule de politesse désignant le destinataire (M. Nom, M. le Fonction) n'a pas de règle, il est possible de l'indenter ou pas.

Ne pas hésiter à faire des paragraphes espacés pour faciliter la lecture, mais éviter les lettres de plusieurs pages.

Une signature pour terminer, à droite.